# Set font-size to parent element (paragraph, h1, h2) in CKEditor

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x

When i set the font-size to the selected text, CKEditor create new element span and set the font-size.

If I set font-size to H1 element, it create new span inside H1 and set the font-size only to span.

The result is a fake line-height.

```
<h1>
    <span style="font-size:10px;">Hello</span>
</h1>

//I want

<h1 style="font-size:10px;">
    <span style="font-size:10px;">Hello</span>
</h1>
```

How can I set the font-size to parent element, h1,h2,p,ecc... in addition to the span?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In CKEDITOR.config there is set_style and [format_h1](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-format_h1)

Other option is to change the styles in contents.css

Comment: The problem is at runtime.
When i change the font size of the span, i want to change the font-size of the parent element, like H1 or Paragraph